# Bootstrap classes do not work in ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I just started learning to use ReactJS to render views, but I found the bootstrap CSS classes don't work as expected if I insert the attributes directly into the ReactJS components. For example, in the below code, I wish to generate a panel with the classes: panel-default and panel-heading; however, the generated view doesn't carry the bootstrap style. I was wondering why and how to fix, if possible. Please note that I've compiled my ReactJS code and included the compiled JS in the HTML code (see at the bottom).

```
var taxonGroups = {
  identifier: 'ABC-x981',
  sources: [
    {segmentName: 'segment1', length: 1090},
    {segmentName: 'segment2', length: 98},
    {segmentName: 'segment3', length: 2091},
    {segmentName: 'segment4', length: 1076},
  ],

  fields: ['Taxon Name', 'Taxon ID', 'Taxon source'],

  collectionDate: '2001-09-10'
};

var Taxon = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div class="panel panel-default"> <div class="panel-heading"><p>{this.props.data.identifier}</p></div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
              {
                this.props.data.sources.map(function(source) {
                  return <Segment name={source.segmentName} length={source.length}/>
                })
                }
          </table>

      </div>
    );
  }
});


var Segment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <tr><td>{this.props.name}</td><td>{this.props.length}</td></tr>
  }

  });

React.render(<Taxon data={taxonGroups} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

**The HTML code:**

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/react/react.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/react/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  <title>reactJS 3 - Rendering data with bootstrap styles</title>
</head>
<body>
<span>Is there anything?</span>

<div id="container">

</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">This is Panel Heading!</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    This is panel body
  </div>
</div>


<script src="scripts/ReactJS/build/taxon.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In React, the attribute is `className`, not `class`. So for example, rather than having

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
```

You should instead have

```
<div className="panel panel-default">
```

By setting it as `class`, React ignores that attribute, and as a result the generated HTML doesn't include the classes the CSS needs.

If you run your expected HTML through the [compiler](http://facebook.github.io/react/html-jsx.html), that is indeed what you get.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when following a React tutorial, i was writing

```
<div classname="my bootstrap code here">
```

instead of

```
<div className="my bootstrap code here">
```

className should be in camel case for jsx. Hope this helps :).